# Options do select com closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para pegar todas tags de options (html e valores) com jquery

```
         <select id="test" name"algumName">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>


<div id="dv">

</div>
```

Estou tentando assim:

```
var options = $(this).closest('#test');
$('#dv').append($('<select name='algumName'>"+ options +"</select>'));
```

Mas não esta dando certo

Comment: Está a tentar colocar os `<options>` dentro do `<div>` ?

Comment: sim, eu fiz uma alteração nos codigos da minha pergunta, para entender melhor

Comment: é justamente o que quero fazer veja essa parte do codigo: `append($('<select name='algumName'>"+ options +"</select>'));`

Comment: Sim estava a escrever no momento que estava a alterar

Comment: @Gislef você quer somente o html dos options? por exemplo, <option value="1">1</option>...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter os options que tem basta apenas alterar o seletor do *Jquery* para `$("#test>option")` que apanha todas as etiquetas `<option>` dentro do `<select>` test.

No entanto para no seu caso é bem mais fácil apanhar o html do `<select>` todo e utilizar na colocação dentro do `<div>`:

```
$('#dv').append('<select name=' + algumName + '>' + $("#test").html() + '</select>');
```

Repare que também coloquei uns `+` que faltavam em `select name='algumName'`

Exemplo:

```js
let algumName = "nome";

$("button").click(function() {
  $('#dv').append('<select name=' + algumName + '>' + $("#test").html() + '</select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" name "algumName">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

<button>Copiar opções</button>

<div id="dv">

</div>
```

**Closest**

Esta função server para percorrer a arvore DOM para cima e apanhar o elemento mais próximo que jogue com o indicado. A pesquisa começa no próprio elemento.

No código que utilizou, `$(this).closest('#test')`, iria apanhar o elemento `#test` caso esse esteja acima, mas continuava a não resolver o problema.

Exemplificando uma utilização simples do `closest`:

```js
$("#p1").closest("h1").css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>
  <p id="p1">texto p1</p>
</h1>
```

Aqui `$("#p1").closest("h1")` apanha o `<h1>` mais próximo de `<p>`, que é o que está exatamente acima.

---

O html pode ser mais complexo que o `closest` tentara na mesma apanhar algum elemento, passando por todos os elementos acima até chegar ao topo:

```js
$("#p1").closest("div").css('background-color','red');
```

```css
div {
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>
    <p id="p1">texto p1</p>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Neste ultimo exemplo foi feito o `closest` para um `<div>`, tentando apanhar o `<div>` mais próximo de `<p>` que é o que está dois níveis acima. Conseguimos ver que foi esse onde foi atribuída a cor devido ao tamanho maior que lhe foi dado neste exemplo.

Comment: Finalmente entendi, excelente! Muito obrigada Isac

Comment: Isac, por exemplo `$(this).closest('th').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').text();` Com este código estou conseguindo acessar o texto da 5 coluna na linha de uma tabela. Tem como minimizar esses 5 `next('td')`? Atualmente pra pegar o valor de cada coluna eu insiro a quantidade de `next('td')` necessarias

Comment: @Gislef É melhor dar me um exemplo do tipo de html que tem para conseguir dar uma solução boa. Para navegação minimamente complexa desse gênero é melhor utilizar o `parent()` e o `find()`. Com tanto `next()` força demasiado a estrutura e fica fácil de quebrar se alguém trocar algo no html.